# Spring MVC controller redirect to some URL after login

Tags: java, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have a Spring MVC Controller with handlers like so:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/account/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String login() {
    return "login";
}


@RequestMapping(value = "/account/login", method = RequestMethod.POST, params = "login")
public String login(@RequestParam(value = "username") String username, 
        @RequestParam(value = "password") String password) {

    // do authentication
    return "home";
}
```

The form in the login.html page POSTs to account/login (the same url). I'd like that after the authentication, I redirect the user to the home page of my application, so that he sees `www.mywebappexample.com` in address bar instead of `www.mywebappexample.com/account/login`. When I return the string from the login method, it renders the proper html but I don't have the URL I want to show. How can I redirect?

**Edit:** I had to prefix my controller return String with `redirect:`. This works if you have a view resolver that subclasses UrlBasedViewResolver [UrlBasedViewResolver](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/UrlBasedViewResolver.html). Thymeleaf's view resolver doesn't do that but it does have the behavior -> [ThymeleafViewResolver](http://www.thymeleaf.org/apidocs/thymeleaf-spring3/2.0.8/org/thymeleaf/spring3/view/ThymeleafViewResolver.html). Here's my servlet-context.xml (I'm using thymeleaf):

```
<bean id="templateResolver"
      class="org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".html"/>
    <property name="templateMode" value="HTML5"/>
</bean>

<bean id="templateEngine" class="org.thymeleaf.spring3.SpringTemplateEngine">
    <property name="templateResolver" ref="templateResolver"/>
</bean>

<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.thymeleaf.spring3.view.ThymeleafViewResolver">
    <property name="templateEngine" ref="templateEngine"/>
    <property name="order" value="1"/>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a redirect in the tag instead which should update the URL in the browser window:

```
return "redirect:home";
```

Comment: This isn't doing it, but I'm assuming it's because I'm using Thymeleaf as my ViewResolver. Doesn't redirect need some other Resolver?

Comment: Haven't used that one. Try `org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver`

Comment: A little playing around with this and it worked. Check my edits if interested.

Comment: +1: `InternalResourceViewResolver` extends `UrlBasedViewResolver` also but may not have all the functionality that you require. :)

Answer (score 0):

Check if the authentication passed successfully and then forward the request with the request dispatcher

```
RequestDispatcher rd = servletContext.getRequestDispatcher("/pathToResource");
 rd.forward(request, response);
```

Comment: I'd really rather not go down to that level. I want to leave it to Spring if it's possible.